# How to configure RedeployPublisher in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

This is my jobs **"RedeployPublisher"** configuration in the **config.xml**. (**"Deploy artifacts to the maven repository"**)

```
<publishers>
    <hudson.maven.RedeployPublisher>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <url>http://repo.internal.com/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
      <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
      <evenIfUnstable>false</evenIfUnstable>
    </hudson.maven.RedeployPublisher>
</publishers>
```

but, now I need to cinfigure this in **"scripted pipline"** jenkinsfile.
Thank you!